# how to stop first function get json till second function getjson return data

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, getjson

Hi Guys I have a problem to make a accordion menu (Nested) in Apache Cordova.
I have to function with two getjson to get categories and sub categories.
Middle of first function i call second function to get sub Categories,But Second Function Did not return my favorite string that is contains htmlSubCategories and it returns undefined value

```
     //Function 1
  var Categoriesdata = [];
function getCategories()
{
    var htmlCategories = "";
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/Categories', null, function (Categoriesdata) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Categoriesdata.length ; i++)
        {
            {
                htmlCategories += "<li>";
                htmlCategories += "<a href='#'> " + Categoriesdata[i].Text + "</a>";
                htmlCategories += getCategoriesRev(Categoriesdata[i].Id);
                htmlCategories += "</li>";
            }
       }
            $(".Categories").html(htmlCategories);  
    });
}

  //Function 2
function getCategoriesRev(Id)
{
    var htmlSubCategories = "";
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/CategoriesRev', { id: Id }, function (CategoriesdataRev) {

        if (CategoriesdataRev.length > 0)
        { 
            for (var j = 0; j < CategoriesdataRev.length; j++) {
                htmlSubCategories += "<li>";
                htmlSubCategories += "<a href='#'> " + CategoriesdataRev[j].Text + "</a>";
                htmlSubCategories += getCategoriesRev(CategoriesdataRev[j].Id);
                htmlSubCategories += "</li>";
            }
            htmlSubCategories = "<ul class='submenu'>" + htmlSubCategories + "</ul>";

        }
  return htmlSubCategories;
    });

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please, explain better

Comment: Have you tried adding `.always(data)` at the end of 2nd function and returning the value inside it? 
This way, you should be able to return data when it is ready.

Comment: what is this part:  `$.getJSON('CategoriesRev'` supposed to do?

Comment: @vahdet can decribe more

Comment: Your both function where calling same data and you haven't added any different elements to set data in your app, you are calling the same function `getCategoriesRev` into it with `i` which is not defined in your second function! Correct your own code first and then let us know if it is working or not.

Comment: @Alirezaunixp I mean something like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981220/4636715  Your $.getJSON have the same functionality as $.ajax with type GET shown there

Comment: Dear @KirankumarDafda I Edited My Code But It did not work

Comment: @Alirezaunixp You can use the callbacks, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40403624/4361743

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are asynchronous, meaning the second call will not be finished by the time it returns and `htmlSubCategories` will still be an empty string.

In JavaScript, you write asynchronous code using callbacks or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Luckily, AJAX requests done with jQuery return you a Promise which you can use.

I would also advise against one AJAX call for each sub category you have. I would only call it once to get all, then filter with JavaScript.

But working with what you have now, the following solution uses simple jQuery:

```
//Function 1
function getCategories()
{
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/Categories', function (Categoriesdata) {
        var $categories = $('.Categories').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < Categoriesdata.length ; i++)
        {
            $categories
                .append('<li>'
                          + '<a href="#">'
                              + Categoriesdata[i].Text
                          + '</a>'
                          + '<ul id="' + Categoriesdata[i].Id + '"></ul>'
                      + '</li>');

            getCategoriesRev(Categoriesdata[i].Id);
        }
    });
}

  //Function 2
function getCategoriesRev(Id)
{
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/CategoriesRev', { id: Id },
        function(CategoriesdataRev) {
            var $subCategoryUl = $('.Categories').find('ul#' + Id);
            if (CategoriesdataRev.length > 0)
            { 
                for (var i = 0; i < CategoriesdataRev.length; i++)
                {
                    $subCategoryUl
                        .addClass('submenu')
                        .append('<li>'
                                  + '<a href="#"> '
                                      + CategoriesdataRev[i].Text
                                  + '</a>'
                              + '</li>');
                }
            }
            else
                $subCategoryUl.remove();
        });
}
```

Comment: Your Code Still returns undefined value

Comment: Correct, both functions are `void`. However, your `$('.Categories')` element should be correctly populated